# How to handle dynamic images in Django?

Tags: django, database, image

For a production Django website with several applications that generate graphs/images based on user input data, how should these images be handled?

- Currently each image is stored to the local folders (e.g. `app1/static/app1`, `app2/static/app2`) folder upon generation.
- Images are then copied using `manage.py collectstatic` to a central folder (e.g. `main_app/static/app1`) from which they are served  (i.e. this folder is  STATIC_ROOT).

The issue is that the images are obviously not found in the main static folder when dynamically generated as I'm relying on `collectstatic` to move them to the STATIC_ROOT.

#### Questions:

- Should dynamic images be served from the local `main_app/static/app1` folder in production (i.e. change STATIC_ROOT)?
- Should the dynamic images be saved to the main directory folder (e.g. `main_app/static/app1`) instead of relying on `collectstatic`?
- Should dynamic images be handled in some other way entirely in production?

***Directory structure and image locations for clarity:***

```
main_app
    settings.py
    models.py
    view.py
    manage.py
    /static/app1     (images copied here using `collectstatic`)
    /static/app2     (images copied here using `collectstatic`)
    /app1
        /static/app1  (images saved here in production)
    /app2
        /static/app2  (images saved here in production)
```

The basis for the above is based on https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/deployment/ , but my spider sense tells me I'm doing this completely wrong.  Using nginx and gunicorn for production.

<sup>As a neophyte I haven't much on this so I'd appreciate some tips on terminology (i.e. these don't seem like they are static images at all, but I've found very little on dynamic images in the documentation).</sup>

Comment: I would put these images in a media folder: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#media-root

Answer (score 1):

I suppose it takes time to generate the images, so it's a good idea to create a task for image generation in your view and pass it to some task queue, e.g. Celery. Let it create the image and save it to media folder, e.g. local `MEDIA_ROOT` or some remote storage like Amazon, and add a link to it to your django model object, that uses this image. Then when the view is requested it will return the link to these images amongst its other content.
See [Managing Files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/files/).

Your images are not really static files, especially if they get 'recalculated' over time. So IMO using `collectstatic` is not the best decision in this case.